# Python style with attributes in class definition

Tags: python

I have a class with some attributes I want to use the methods. What is the most pythonic way to use it?. Is there  documentation I can read about these styles issues?. I use pylint and pep8 to fix this kind of issues, but these program don't show any errors in this example with the attribute

```
class A(object):
        BLOCK_SIZE = 8192

        def func1(self):
                print self.BLOCK_SIZE
        def func2(self):
                print A.BLOCK_SIZE
```

If I understand correctly this two case are the same, but I don't
know if is better to refer the class name or use the self reference.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should prefer `self`.

There are two types of fields - Class variables and Object variables.

Class variables are shared in the sense that they are accessed by all objects (instances) of that class. There is only copy of the class variable and when any one object makes a change to a class variable, the change is reflected in all the other instances as well.

Object variables are owned by each individual object/instance of the class. In this case, each object has its own copy of the field i.e. they are not shared and are not related in any way to the field by the same name in a different instance of the same class.

By using `A.BLOCK_SIZE` - you get class variable while by using `self.BLOCK_SIZE` you get an attribute of the specific object.

Check this to get a detailed example and explanations.
https://www.ibiblio.org/g2swap/byteofpython/read/class-and-object-vars.html

Comment: In addition, all UPPERCASE should only be use for global constants, shouldn't it?

Comment: I don't remember anything like this in PEP8, but acording to the Django style guide it's possible to use UPPERCASE variables inside a class.

Comment: Also according to PEP8 global variable naming conventions are the same as for functions.
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#global-variable-names

Comment: Hi @OlexanderYermakov , my problem is not the access (I know the object attribute vs class variable issue you describe). In my case all I want a single constant attached to the class (I'm not going to modify it), and I don't know what is the best pithonic way of doing it. After read your responses (and the one from Serge Ballesta, I'm going to use the self.atrribute

Answer (score 1):

A class attribute can more or less be used as the default value for an instance attribute. The language allow a class attribute to be read either from the class itself or from any instance of the class, provided the instance has no attribute of same name.

But things go differently for write access: `A.BLOCK_SIZE=16384` will change the global class attribute, while `self.BLOCK_SIZE=16384` will create (or update) an instance attribute of same name.

Here is a little example with your class:

```
>>> a = A()
>>> a.func1()               # access the class attribute
8192
>>> a.func2()               # access the class attribute too
8192
>>> a.BLOCK_SIZE=4096       # create an instance attribute of same name
>>> a.func1()               # access the INSTANCE attribute
4096
>>> a.func2()               # still access the class attribute
8192
```

That's the reason why you should under common circonstances use the instance semantics (`self.BLOCK_SIZE`) because it does not rely on the class name and allows per instance override.

The class semantics `A.BLOCK_SIZE` should only be used if you want to change the class attribute, or need to use the class attribute even if an instance attribute exists.